# Select date with n days from the date added

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a mysql table with the following fields

```
Name | Email | Date | Status
```

I want to extract the records where date range is between 30 days

Assume today is 2014/12/9

ie. date values are

```
2014/11/25 

2014/12/2

2014/12/1

2014/10/25

2014/11/9
```

I need the o/p as (the number of days should be with in 30 days from the db date to today date)

```
2014/11/25 

2014/12/2

2014/12/1

2014/11/9
```

I want to extract records those have the interval of less than 30 days from the date in the db.

Yes. I want to fetch the record between 2 days. For this I used this query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_jobboard WHERE dtDate <= ( dtDate +30 )
```

But it is not working.

How to write the select query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select data from date range between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208958/select-data-from-date-range-between-two-dates)

Comment: Yes. I want to fetch the record between 2 days. For this I used this query SELECT * 
FROM  `tbl_jobboard` 
WHERE  `dtDate` <= ( dtDate +30 ) . But it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

USE [`DATE_SUB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Working Fiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6344f2/1

Answer (score 0):

use following query

```
select * from table_Name t where t.date<=now() and t.date>=DATE_SUB(now(),
INTERVAL 31 DAY)
```