# Fetching records with same Id but between two given dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like below:

### MyTable

```
FileNo: |  amount | date
---------------------------------------------------
111     | 55      | 2017-04-07 04:51:45.870
111     | 55      | 2017-04-08 04:51:45.870
111     | 55      | 2017-04-09 04:51:45.870
111     | 55      | 2017-04-10 04:51:45.870
999     | 55      | 2017-04-11 04:51:45.870
111     | 55      | 2017-04-12 04:51:45.870
999     | 55      | 2017-04-13 04:51:45.870
111     | 55      | 2017-04-14 04:51:45.870
999     | 55      | 2017-04-15 04:51:45.870
```

Now I want to fetch records where FileNo: is '111' and date between '04/07/2017' and '04/10/2017'

I have written my query like below:-

```
select * from MyTable where FileNo: = 111 and date >= '04/07/2017' and date <= '04/10/2017'
```

But it didn't work, there was no error found, It didn't return any records, it just showed empty table!, is my syntax wrong or am I missing  'Group By' or any other Clause?

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select data from date range between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208958/select-data-from-date-range-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is MSSQL Server then try

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE FileNo: = 111
  AND CAST(date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2017-07-04' AND '2017-10-04'
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

Your date literals are in a wrong format.  Try using the ANSI standard `yyyy-MM-dd` instead:

```
select *
from MyTable
where FileNo: = 111 and
      date between '2017-07-04' and '2017-10-04'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from MyTable where FileNo: = 111 and date >= '04/07/2017' and date <= '04/10/2017'
```

This query is correct thus why you haven't seen any error's. However, no dates will be matched.

Please note that:

- `2017-04-07 04:51:45.870` = `07 April 2017`; and
- `04/10/2017` = `04 October 2017`

So you will never expect to see any results there.

**Solution**

```
select * from MyTable where FileNo: = 111 and date >= '2017-04-07' and date <= '2017-04-15'
```

As well remove the time use only date ie `yyyy-MM-dd` NOT `yyyy-MM-dd hhmmss`