# Is it possible to loop the result of a query that gets each revenue for the last 8 weeks based on the input date of the user?

Tags: php, sql, database, loops

User input = '2017-03-12'

Let say I have this tableRevenue

```
   date        revenue   
  ----------   ---------
 2017-01-01     100
 2017-01-08     100
 2017-01-15     100
 2017-01-22     100 
 2017-01-29     100
 2017-01-05     100
 2017-01-12     100
 2017-02-19     100
 2017-02-26     100
 2017-03-05     100
 2017-03-12     100
```

And another tableHolidays which contains

```
 date
----------
2017-01-15
2017-02-19
2017-03-05
```

I want to display it like this:

```
   date        revenue   
  ----------   ---------
 2017-01-01     100
 2017-01-08     100
 2017-01-22     100 
 2017-01-29     100
 2017-01-05     100
 2017-01-12     100
 2017-02-26     100
 2017-03-12     100
```

I want to display the revenue each of the last 8 weeks and I want to skip all the dates that are existing in tableHolidays using a loop. Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: every thing is possible. first what have you tried so far?

Comment: I do not see any link between these dates, could you be more explicit on what you want to achieve? Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208958/select-data-from-date-range-between-two-dates ?

Comment: which kind of SQL? mySQL? SQL-Server? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mention: you didn't tag any specific database - my answer will refer to SQL-Server:

assuming @UserDate is a variable with the user input date

1. Use Date-Functions (specific to every DB system) to calculate the date range. in your case to subtract the 8 weeks.
2. Select all rows within this date range
3. exclude (`NOT IN`) all dates from your resultset which occur in your `tableHolidays` table
4. `GROUP BY` weeks (calculate weeknumber with `WEEK`) and `SUM` the revenue

Query:

```
  SELECT WEEK(tR.date) as weeknr
        ,SUM(tR.revenue)
    FROM tableRevenue tR
   WHERE tR.date >= DATEADD(wk,-8,@UserDate)
     AND tR.date <= @UserDate
     AND tR.date NOT IN (SELECT date FROM tableHolidays)
GROUP BY WEEK(tR.date)
```

Comment: It still display all the dates per day. I just want to show the revenue of the same day but past week.

Comment: @LanzJoshua: now i know what you're want to do. you finally just want to group all your rows by week. i just updated my answer. have a look

Comment: MYSQL said:
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: @LanzJoshua i updated my answer again. for the future: please always tag the database system you are using. in example, my solution included the DATEDIFF function, which is MS SQL specific and not recognized in mysql. i changed it now to the function WEEK() which is known by mysql

Answer (score 0):

> you can use the 'ANY' which is a mysql operator
>   for more information you can visit this link
>   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_any_all.asp

```
$userInput = '2017-03-12';
$sql = "SELECT  `date`, `revenue`
FROM `tableRevenue`
WHERE ( 
 (`date` = ANY 
   (SELECT `date` FROM `tableHolidays` WHERE DATE(date)<='{$userInput}'))  
 AND (DATE(date) <='{$userInput}')
)";
```

Comment: I can't use "any" because I need the specific dates: (1)2017-03-05, (2)2017-2-26, (3)2017-02-19, (4)2017-02-12, (5)2017-02-05, (6)2017-01-29, (7)2017-01-22, (8)2017-01-15