# Fetch data between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know how to fetch data between two dates using SQL queries. In my table date format is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm`.

According to these dates format I need to fetch data. Column is DATE type.

I tried with below query

```
select * from sales 
where to_char(txn_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy' ) 
between '10-09-2018' and '30-09-2018'
```

I am getting wrong records. Why?

Comment: don't store datetimes as strings.

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server)?  What is the type of your date column?  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: @MitchWheat I wouldn't presume that this means the column is text (though it could be).  I won't counter your downvote, however, due to no effort being shown.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen : pretty difficult to have a format if it's not a string....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select data from date range between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208958/select-data-from-date-range-between-two-dates)

Comment: I am using sql queries in my oracle db

Comment: @Tim....coloumn is date type and I tried with below queries "select *from sales where to_char(txn_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy' ) between 10-09-2018 and 30-09-2018"

Comment: I am getting wrong records

Comment: Please post some sample data which reproduces the problem, and an indication of the records you expect it to return.

Comment: For future reference, please **edit your question** to provide clarification or additional information. In particular, code is hard to read in comments due to poor formatting.

Comment: @RakeshDivedi If you have got an answer to your question, please accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're saving the timestamps as `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` in the database. If that is the case, you can't. And it's a really bad approach. Please use type `DATETIME` instead, which enables you to use the `BETWEEN` operator.

When you're using the `DATETIME` type, you can do

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
WHERE txn_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Which will give you all the data in the year of 2018 and still using your indexes

**EDIT**

Since you've now told that you're using `DATE` as data type, you can use the same solution, without the time.

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
WHERE txn_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```

Comment: In table txn_date has date data type

Answer (score 0):

You are getting wrong records because you are converting the dates into a string. That means the query uses string semantics when doing the comparison. As a string, `'15-12-2999'` and `'15-05-2000` are between `'10-09-2018'` and `'30-09-2018'` because `'15'` has a higher ASCII value than `'10'` and a lower ASCII value than `'30'`.

The solution is quite simple: use date datatypes for the comparison.

```
select * from sales 
where txn_date between date '2018-09-10' and date '2018-09-30'
```

If TXN_DATE has a time element you may want to change the query to

```
select * from sales 
where txn_date >= date '2018-09-10' 
and txn_date < date '2018-10-01'
```

Otherwise you will not retrieve records for transactions made after midnight on 30th September.

Alternatively you could remove the time element by truncating the date:

```
select * from sales 
where trunc(txn_date) between date '2018-09-10' and date '2018-09-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from sales 
where trunc(txn_date )
between '10-09-2018' and '30-09-2018' If you have the format date/time trunc would eliminate the time in the date

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer for this question
Select *from sales where txn_date between to_date('01-10-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') And to_date('31-10-2018 23:59:59','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')