# LLD Car Rental Application SpringBoot | How to reserve a car for particular days so that other users can't re-book it for same period

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, database-design, entity

I am trying to solve a low level design problem for car rental application. I have created below models/entities.

```java
public class Car{
    private long id;
    private Type type;
    private String licenseNum;
    private Color color;
    private Location location;
    //other details
    //Color is enum for values RED, WHITE etc
    //TYPE is enum for values SEDAN, SUV, HATCHBACK etc
    //Location is another class that contains location related details
}

public class Booking{
    private long id;
    private Date bookingStartDay;//day of booking
    private int bookingDays;//number of days of the booking, maximum value 50
    private User userId;
    private Location pickUpLoc;
    private Location dropLoc;
    //User is another entity having user details such as id, name, address etc.
}
```

A user can book a car for upto 50 days. Now, suppose one user is booking a car A from 1st Oct, 2022 for 3 days (i.e till 3rd Oct, 2022). To make sure other users can't book car A for 1st Oct, 2022. I have created a class BookCar which will use **carId** from entity Car and **bookingStartDay** from entity Booking as its composite key.

```java
public class BookCar{
    private long carId;
    private Date bookingStartDay;
    //carId and bookingStartDay forms a composite key;
    private User user;
    private BookingStatus status;
    //BookingStatus is an enum with values CANCELLED, RESERVED
}
```

So, booking status for composite key (carId for A,01-10-2022) will be RESERVED in BookCar entity.

But there is a problem. Car A is booked from 1st Oct, 2022 to 3rd Oct, 2022. But if another user tries to book Car A for 2nd Oct, 2022. It wil shown as available because in BookCar, car A is reserved for (carId for A,01-10-2022) only not for 1st Oct, 2022 to 3rd Oct, 2022.

So, how can I store range of days in my BookCar table. So, that no other user can book the car for reserved days.

I have other questions.

1. Is there any other way to reserve the car for a range of days so that other users can't book it?
2. For car A booking from 1st Oct, 2022 to 3rd Oct, 2022, I add records for (carId for A,01-10-2022), (carId for A,02-10-2022), (carId for A,013-10-2022) in BookCar table. Then, for booking of maximum 50 days for a car, 50 rows will be added in BookCar table or simply 50 write operations will be performed on this table. Is it good a approach to achieve it?
   I am using MySQL database for this application.

Please try to answer from interview perspective.

Comment: 1.  It's reasonable to expect that the application will do some date checking so that it's not all up to the database.  Having said that, you can create a `BookCar` row for each day of the booking.  2.  Assuming 200 cars in the inventory, all rented for 50 days, you'd have 10,000 rows in your `BookCar` table.  That's not a large table.

Comment: Hi @GilbertLeBlanc, thanks for commenting. For 1 booking of Car A for 50 days, we are adding 50 records in table BookCar and then there won't be any write operation for Car A for the next 50 days. Only read operations will be there. And if one user wants to book car A, then we have to search only 1 record i.e. composite (car A id, Date) that's it. Is it a good approach?

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Please clarify via edits, not ccmments. [ask] [Help] What parts of this are you able to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my vieq, we can use just two sql tables for booking. This is an example how classes can be looked based on sql tables:

```
public class Car {
    private long id;
    private Type type;      
    // other code is omitted for the brevity
}

public class Booking {
    private long id;
    private User userId;
    private long carId;
    private Date bookingStartDay; // day of booking
    private Date bookingFinishDay; // when user should return car
    
    // other code is omitted for the brevity
}
```

### What should we do when user book a car?

**Case 1: There is no booking in booking table by `carId`**

We will just insert row in `Booking` table with date start (column `bookingStartDay`) and finish date (column `bookingFinishDay`). So if user book car `car_1` from 1 october till 3 october, then we need to insert the following row in `Booking` table:

```
Booking:
    id: 1
    userId: 1
    carId: 1
    bookingStartDay: 2022-10-01
    bookingFinishDay: 2022-10-03
```

We will **not add** any additional 3 rows in `Booking`   table.

**Case 2: If there are bookings in booking table by `carId`**

We are running sql query which will check whether user's desired date is within `bookingStartDay` and `bookingFinishDay`.

For example, user want to book a car with `id = 1` from  1 October to 3 october, then [you can run a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208958/select-data-from-date-range-between-two-dates) to check whether your `RangeFrom` and `RangeTill` are within date range between two dates `bookingStartDay` and `bookingFinishDay`:

```
SELECT * FROM Booking 
WHERE NOT (From_date > @RangeTill OR To_date < @RangeFrom)
    AND carId = 1
```

Then you can return a message to user whether the car is available to be booked based on result of your query.

Comment: Hi, @StepUp thank you so much for answering. But one doubt,  I am adding record in Booking table only when the booking for car (A) is fixed suppose from 1st Oct, to 3rd Oct. Now, in Booking table if there are multiple bookings for car A for couple of next months or year then there will be multiple bookings for periods like (1st Oct, 3rd Oct), (15th Oct, 20th Oct) .. and so...on. Let there are 50 bookings that are present for car A in table Booking. Before running the SQL command given by you , do I need to fetch all those 50 booking records for car A to check other user can book it or not?

Comment: Because JOIN SQL query given by you is working on 1 Car A and its 1 booking. That means for car A with multiple bookings, we have to run this query for all its bookings. Suppose number of bookings is 50 for next 3 months. We are ofcourse not adding 50 new records but we are reading 50 records for other booking. Which is obviously better than adding new records but is there any simpler way to achieve that or may be I misunderstood your approach?

Comment: @MayankKumarThakur there is no need add additional 50 records. You can just create two columns such as  `bookingStartDay` and `bookingFinishDay`. I've refactored my approach. Please, see my updated answer